# HTML video type attribute requires video before /

Tags: html, html5-video

In an HTML5 video element you define the `type` attribute with a value that always starts with video. Isn't it already obvious from the element being a video, that it is of type video? Why is video required like this:
`type="video/mp4"`, shouldn't it be just `type="mp4"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media types always come in pairs like `video/mp4`.  Also, browsers do actually allow audio in a `<video>` element.  You can include a poster image to display a fixed image.  This may be useful if you are listing multiple sources for a `<video>` element, some of which are video.  When you list multiple sources, the browser will play the first one with a supported media type.

Example:

```
<video poster="albumcover.jpg" controls>
    <source src="musicvideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="musicaudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</video>
```

In this example, if the browser supports WebM video it will play that.  If it does not support WebM video but it supports MP3 audio then it will play that instead.

Comment: I really like this answer and did not consider this kind of corner case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

video/mp4 is a Mime Type:
[Mime Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

You must use it because it's correct to use the complete mime type 'video/mp4' also if it's obviously a video

Answer (score 0):

In the w3schools, they define the possible formats and MIME types we are supposed to use for it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp).

**MP4**:    video/mp4

**WebM**:   video/webm

**Ogg**:    video/ogg

They use MIME types, so it will fit the huge set of 'global MIME types' for compatibility and reference reasons. See [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/).